# Prestashop WebService: Add a product

Tags: web-services, prestashop

Hi guys i'm trying to add a new product via web services using the PSWebServiceLibrary, i tried to read other posts in this forum but i have problems.

That's my code:

```
function AddProduct($root_path, $authentication_key, $id, $name, $desc, $cat, $qta, $price){
    try{
        $webService = CreateWebServer($root_path,$authentication_key);
        $xml = $webService->get(array('resource' => 'products?schema=synopsis'));
    }catch(PrestashopWebserviceException $ex){
        echo $ex->getMessage();
        return -1;
    }


    $resources = $xml->children()->children();

    unset($resources->position_in_category);
    unset($resources->manufacturer_name);

    $resources->price = floatval($price);
    $resources->quantity = intval($qta);
    $resources->link_rewrite->language[0][0] = str_replace(' ','-',$name);
    $resources->name->language[0][0] = $name;
    $resources->description->language[0][0] = $desc;

    $node= dom_import_simplexml($resources->description->language[0][0]);
    $no = $node->ownerDocument;
    $node->appendChild($no->createCDATASection($desc));

    $resources->associations = '';

   //echo $xml->asXML();
    try{
        $opt = array('resource' => 'products');
        $opt['postXml'] = $xml->asXML();
        $xml = $webService->add($opt);
    }
    catch(PrestaShopWebserviceException $ex)
    {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this funcion it gives me error:

> This call to PrestaShop Web Services failed and returned an HTTP status of 400. That means: Bad Request.

I think there's a sort of problem with the "required=true" parameters, but i don't know what to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my function now and it works

```
function CreateProduct($update, $webService, $root_path, $n_id, $n_id_category_default, $n_id_category, $n_price, $n_active,$n_avail4order,$n_show_price, $n_id_stock_availables ,$n_id_id_product_attribute, $n_l_id, $n_name, $n_desc, $n_desc_short, $n_link_rewrite, $n_meta_title, $n_meta_description, $n_meta_keywords,$n_available_now,$n_available_later,$idtaglist,$cod) {

$xml = $webService -> get(array('url' => $root_path . '/api/products?schema=blank'));
$resources = $xml -> children() -> children();
unset($resources -> id);
unset($resources -> position_in_category);
unset($resources -> id_shop_default);
unset($resources -> date_add);
unset($resources -> date_upd);

unset($resources->associations->combinations);
unset($resources->associations->product_options_values);
unset($resources->associations->product_features);
unset($resources->associations->stock_availables->stock_available->id_product_attribute);

//unset($resources->associations->categories->category->id);

//unset($resources-> id_category_default);

//$resources->position_in_category = '0';
//unset($resources->position_in_category);

//$resources -> position = '0';
if($update) $resources-> id = $n_id;
$resources-> id_manufacturer = '1';
$resources-> id_supplier = '1';
$resources-> id_category_default = $n_id_category_default;
$resources-> new = '0'; ; //condition, new is also a php keyword!!
$resources-> cache_default_attribute;
$resources-> id_default_image;
$resources-> id_default_combination = '0';
$resources-> id_tax_rules_group ='1';
//$resources-> id_shop_default;
//$resources-> quantity = '50';
$resources-> reference = $cod;
$resources-> supplier_reference;
$resources-> location;
$resources-> width;
$resources-> height;
$resources-> depth;
$resources-> weight;
$resources-> quantity_discount;
$resources-> ean13;
$resources-> upc;
$resources-> cache_is_pack;
$resources-> cache_has_attachments;
$resources-> is_virtual;
$resources-> on_sale;
$resources-> online_only;
$resources-> ecotax;
//$resources-> minimal_quantity = 10;
$resources-> price = $n_price;
$resources-> wholesale_price;
$resources-> unity;
$resources-> unit_price_ratio;
$resources-> additional_shipping_cost;
$resources-> customizable;
$resources-> text_fields;
$resources-> uploadable_files;
$resources-> active = $n_active;
$resources-> available_for_order = $n_avail4order;
$resources-> available_date;
$resources-> condition;
$resources-> show_price = $n_show_price;
$resources-> indexed = '1';
$resources-> visibility = 'both';
$resources-> advanced_stock_management='0';
$resources-> date_add;
$resources-> date_upd;

$resources->associations->categories->addChild('category')->addChild('id', $n_id_category);

$node = dom_import_simplexml($resources -> name -> language[0][0]);
$no = $node -> ownerDocument;
$node -> appendChild($no -> createCDATASection($n_name));
$resources -> name -> language[0][0] = $n_name;
$resources -> name -> language[0][0]['id'] = $n_l_id;
$resources -> name -> language[0][0]['xlink:href'] = $root_path . '/api/languages/' . $n_l_id;

$node = dom_import_simplexml($resources -> description -> language[0][0]);
$no = $node -> ownerDocument;
$node -> appendChild($no -> createCDATASection($n_desc));
$resources -> description -> language[0][0] = $n_desc;
$resources -> description -> language[0][0]['id'] = $n_l_id;
$resources -> description -> language[0][0]['xlink:href'] = $root_path . '/api/languages/' . $n_l_id;

$node = dom_import_simplexml($resources -> description_short -> language[0][0]);
$no = $node -> ownerDocument;
$node -> appendChild($no -> createCDATASection($n_desc_short));
$resources -> description_short -> language[0][0] = $n_desc_short;
$resources -> description_short -> language[0][0]['id'] = $n_l_id;
$resources -> description_short -> language[0][0]['xlink:href'] = $root_path . '/api/languages/' . $n_l_id;

$node = dom_import_simplexml($resources -> link_rewrite -> language[0][0]);
$no = $node -> ownerDocument;
$node -> appendChild($no -> createCDATASection($n_link_rewrite));
$resources -> link_rewrite -> language[0][0] = $n_link_rewrite;
$resources -> link_rewrite -> language[0][0]['id'] = $n_l_id;
$resources -> link_rewrite -> language[0][0]['xlink:href'] = $root_path . '/api/languages/' . $n_l_id;

$node = dom_import_simplexml($resources -> meta_title -> language[0][0]);
$no = $node -> ownerDocument;
$node -> appendChild($no -> createCDATASection($n_meta_title));
$resources -> meta_title -> language[0][0] = $n_meta_title;
$resources -> meta_title -> language[0][0]['id'] = $n_l_id;
$resources -> meta_title -> language[0][0]['xlink:href'] = $root_path . '/api/languages/' . $n_l_id;

$node = dom_import_simplexml($resources -> meta_description -> language[0][0]);
$no = $node -> ownerDocument;
$node -> appendChild($no -> createCDATASection($n_meta_description));
$resources -> meta_description -> language[0][0] = $n_meta_description;
$resources -> meta_description -> language[0][0]['id'] = $n_l_id;
$resources -> meta_description -> language[0][0]['xlink:href'] = $root_path . '/api/languages/' . $n_l_id;

$node = dom_import_simplexml($resources -> meta_keywords -> language[0][0]);
$no = $node -> ownerDocument;
$node -> appendChild($no -> createCDATASection($n_meta_keywords));
$resources -> meta_keywords -> language[0][0] = $n_meta_keywords;
$resources -> meta_keywords -> language[0][0]['id'] = $n_l_id;
$resources -> meta_keywords -> language[0][0]['xlink:href'] = $root_path . '/api/languages/' . $n_l_id;

$node = dom_import_simplexml($resources -> available_now -> language[0][0]);
$no = $node -> ownerDocument;
$node -> appendChild($no -> createCDATASection($n_available_now));
$resources -> available_now -> language[0][0] = $n_available_now;
$resources -> available_now -> language[0][0]['id'] = $n_l_id;
$resources -> available_now -> language[0][0]['xlink:href'] = $root_path . '/api/languages/' . $n_l_id;

$node = dom_import_simplexml($resources -> available_later -> language[0][0]);
$no = $node -> ownerDocument;
$node -> appendChild($no -> createCDATASection($n_available_later));
$resources -> available_later -> language[0][0] = $n_available_later;
$resources -> available_later -> language[0][0]['id'] = $n_l_id;
$resources -> available_later -> language[0][0]['xlink:href'] = $root_path . '/api/languages/' . $n_l_id;

//echo '<br/><br/>';
//aggiungo i tag
foreach ($idtaglist as $tag){
    $resources->associations->tags->addChild('tags')->addChild('id', $tag);
    //$resources -> asssociations -> tags -> tags -> id = $tag;
    //echo $resources -> asssociations -> tags -> tags -> id.'--'.$tag.'<br/>'; 
}

$id = "";
try {
    $opt = array('resource' => 'products');
    if(!$update){
        $opt['postXml'] = $xml -> asXML();
        $xml = $webService -> add($opt);
        $id = $xml->product->id;
    }
    else{
        $opt['putXml'] = $xml -> asXML();
        //echo 'n_id: '.$n_id;
        $opt['id'] = $n_id; 
        $xml = $webService -> edit($opt);
        $id = $n_id;
    }

} catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $ex) {
    //echo '<b>Error : '.$ex->getMessage().'</b>';
}
return $id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You where trying to pass "quantity" in you xml
beware both **"quantity" and "manufacturer_name" are read only properties** that's why it gives back error.